# How to read by the number at each iteration of the loop in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, file

How to read by the number at each iteration of the loop? Dynamic work is important, (not once to read the entire line and convert to an array), at each iteration, take one number from the file string and work with it. How to do it right?

input.txt :

```
5
1 7 5 2 3
```

Work with 2nd line of the file.

```
fin     = File.open("input.txt", "r")
fout    = File.open("output.txt", "w")
n       = fin.readline.to_i

heap_min = Heap.new(:min)
heap_max = Heap.new(:max)

for i in 1..n

    a = fin.read.to_i #code here <-- 

    heap_max.push(a)
    if heap_max.size > heap_min.size
        tmp = heap_max.top
        heap_max.pop
        heap_min.push(tmp)
    end 
    if heap_min.size > heap_max.size
        tmp = heap_min.top
        heap_min.pop
        heap_max.push(tmp)
    end 
    if heap_max.size == heap_min.size
        heap_max.top > heap_min.top ? median = heap_min.top : median = heap_max.top
    else
        median = heap_max.top
    end
    fout.print(median, " ")
end
```

Comment: That heap-related code looks irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're 100% sure that your file separate numbers by space you can try this :

```
a = fin.gets(' ', -1).to_i
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the 2nd line of a file:

```
line2 =  File.readlines('input.txt')[1]
```

Convert it to an array of integers:

```
array = line2.split(' ').map(&:to_i).compact
```

Comment: Slurping files is a dangerous habit :)

Comment: This solution is not for my task because i don't need array -> ONLY DYNAMIC WORK

Comment: you have not explained what you actually need help with. What do you even mean by "dynamic work"?